# Non-blocking TCP socket handling - How to detect blocking state prior to writing on to the socket?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I'm currently writing a proxy application that reads from one socket and writes on another. Both are set as non-blocking, allowing multiple sockets pairs to be handle.

To control a proper flow between the sockets, the application should NOT read from the source socket if the writing on the target socket may block.
The idea is nice, however I found no way to detect a blocking state of the target socket without first writing to it... and that is not what is needed.

I know of an option to use `SIOCOUTQ` (using `ioctl()`) and calculate the remaining buffer, but this seems ugly compared to a simple check if the target socket is ready for writing.

I guess I can also use `select()` for just this socket, but that is so much waste of a such heavy system call.

Comment: I think SIOCOUTQ may be your only safe bet, otherwise you may read more than can be written anyway (say you read 8k and can write 1k, still 7k you've read too quickly, not much better than the 8k without checking at all.

Comment: The application keeps fairness between connections, therefore, it will read only a maximum number of bytes (say 2K) and no more. But I accept your remark on this, even if the socket is ready for writing, I may have only half of the portion to transmit and I get stuck with the rest. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: I think this idea is not 100% explained `To control a proper flow between the sockets, the application should NOT read from the source socket if the writing on the target socket may block. `. Why you cannot have a small portion of data for a connection that you proxy that has been read but not written yet?

Comment: Because that will require the proxy application to buffer things, and I want to avoid that. It has a good reason except the simplification of it... If I do buffering, I loose the flow control between the two connections/sockets.

Comment: a) What do you mean by flow control? b) the only safe way I can think of doing what you want is to read 1 byte, write 1 byte..

Comment: a)Flow Control in this context is targeting this scenario: the target socket may have a link of 1Mbps and the source socket a link of 10Mbps, flow control will assure that the source link will be read at a rate of ~1Mbps and the TCP stack will manage the rest (tell the other peer to slow down). b)As it was remarked before, there is actually a way... at least on Linux and some other Unix like OS by reading the buffer size of the target socket. I will add a summary of one optional answer to this thread using it. Thanks.

Comment: I think with your definition of `Flow Control` you will not loose it. First how you can archive this `flow control will assure that the source link will be read at a rate of ~1Mbps` if it can be read at 10Mbs? Is it the average speed? If so, I see no problem. Even if you have your own data buffer you will have the same average speed.

Comment: Because I will not read the source socket if I cannot write to the target socket.. assuming I write to the target socket at a rate of 1Mbps, I will also read at the same rate. If we have a buffer in between, we will potentially read at the maximum speed of 10Mbps, and release it to the target at 1Mbps, this will require handling and will introduce delay, jittering and a large amount of memory usage in case we get to a large number of sockets (not scalable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for the feedback.

Summarizing all comments and answers up until now:

Directly to the question, the only known way to detect that a socket will block on an attempt to write to it is using `select`/`poll`/`epoll`.

The original objective was to build a proxy, which reads from one socket and writes to another, keeping proper balance between them (reading at the same rate of writing and vice versa) and using no major buffering in the application. For this, the following options were presented:

1. Use of `SIOCOUTQ` to find out how much buffer is left on the destination socket and transmit no more than that. As pointed out by *@ugoren*, this has a disadvantage of being unreliable, mainly because in between reading the value, calculating it and attempting to write the actual value may change. It also introduces some issues of busy-waiting if wrongly managed. I guess, if this technique is to be used, it should be followed by a more reliable one for full protection.
2. Use of `select`/`poll`/`epoll` and adding a small limited buffer per read socket: Initially, all read sockets will be added to the `poll`, when ready for read, we read it in a limited buffer size, then remove the read socket from the `poll` and add instead of it the destination socket for writing, when we return to the `poll` and we detect that the destination socket is ready for writing, we write the buffer, if all data was accepted by the socket, we remove the destination socket from the poll and return the read socket back. The disadvantage here is that we increase the number of system calls (adding/removing to the `poll`/`select`) and we need to keep an internal buffer per socket. This seems to be the preferred approach, and some optimization could be added to try and reduce the call to system calls (for example, trying to write right after reading the read socket, and only if something is left to perform the above).

Thank you all again for participating in this discussion, it helped me a lot ordering the ideas.

Answer (score 1):

`select` or `poll` should be able to give you the information.
I assume you're already using one of them to detect which of your reading sockets has data
When you have a reading socket available for read, replace it with the corresponding writing socket (but put it in the write fds of course), and call `select` again. Then, if the writing socket is available, you can read and write.

Note that it's possible that the writing socket is ready to get data, but not as much as you want. So you might manage to read 100 bytes, and write only 50.

Comment: The last note is the one that breaks things up. I do not want to manage the rest of the data, therefore, in this case I will prefer to block until I can send it all. Seems like the SIOCOUTQ is a better approach as Joachim remarked.

Comment: You want to know not only if you can send, but how much. SIOCOUTQ seems to give it. But I'm not sure it's 100% reliable (can things change between SIOCUOTQ and real send?) Also, what do you do if you get size 0? You don't want a busy wait until it changes.

Comment: I guess that if it changes, it will in the "good" direction (more buffers are free, as more data was sent successfully). if I get a zero or less than what I consider the minimum, I will not read from the source socket and pass on to the next one. I will come back to the same source socket again after the next call to select/pool/epoll.

Comment: It should usually change in the good direction, but I doubt if it's guaranteed (maybe memory shortage will cause the OS to reduce buffers). And if you have no other sockets, select/poll/epoll will wake up again (because your read socket is still available), and you'll find yourself busy-looping.

Comment: Good points, thanks. For the first one, I can protect such a situation by blocking until I can send (with a timeout), but I guess this is really extreme... The second point...hmmm.. hard :) I guess I can add a counter for attempts per socket, removing the source socket from the select() and raising a timer service with a callback that re-adds it again to the select. What do you think?

Comment: I think write fds, to which you want to write but can't, should be added to select.