# select socket call send and recv synchronization

Tags: sockets, network-programming

I am using the select call and accepting the connection from "X" no of clients.
I made duplex connection i.e. server to client and client to server.
When connection is established between 2 entities ,I am going to send
data in chunks from one entity to other.
During send I read one file in chunks and send the data in chunks.

```
while(file_size !=0)
{
    read_bytes = read(fd, buff, sizeof(buff));
    cnt_ = send(_sock_fd,buff,actually_read,0);
    file_size = file_size - cnt_;
    printf("total sent remaining %d : %d\n",size,actually_read);
}
```

while at receiver side 
//First I send the header which contain size it got accepted fine but during the following send call I used "get_readable_bytes" (Using ioctl) which returns me the no of bytes arrived at socket 
`while(size != 0)
    {
        int test_ = 0;

```
    while(((cnt_= get_readable_bytes(_sock_fd))== 0) )//&& test_ == 0
    {
        cnt_= get_n_readable_bytes(_sock_fd);
        printf("Total bytes recved %d\n",cnt_);
        //test_ = test_ + 1;
    }

    while(cnt_ != 0)
    {
        actually_read = recv(_sock_fd, buff, sizeof(buff),0);
        int _cnt = get_n_readable_bytes(_sock_fd);
        printf("Total bytes recved %d\n",cnt_-_cnt);
        write(_fd,buff,actually_read);
        cnt_ = cnt_ - actually_read;
        test_ = 0;
    }
```

`Now the problem is
1.During this execution of receive function control automatically go to the select function and it tries to execute whole receive function again so is there any way to synchronize the sender and receivers such that when the sender complete then start receiver or as soon as sender start receiver ?
2.And how do I maintain the count of bytes sent and received.
and this is my select call

```
`is_read_availble = select(maxfd + 1,&read_set,NULL,NULL,&timeout)`
```

with timeout 10sec.

Comment: Well: don't put the write part of your function in the read-handler of the select part, than. Either you put a extra fd_set for write in the select loop, or you check every time if there is anyting left to write in your read buffer. Calling select() while you still have work to do is what blocks you. In most cases, it is convenient to have some kind of buffer structure per (pair of) filedescriptor(s).

Comment: I think this one may help you a bit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148178/non-blocking-tcp-socket-handling-how-to-detect-blocking-state-prior-to-writing

Answer (score 0):

Sketch of the kind of buffer code you need. (To allow partial reads/writes, the buffers need to be persistent between calls) BTW: you **really** need to handle the -1 return from read() and write() because they would seriously disturb your buffer-bookkeeping. EINTR + EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK is very common.

```
struct buff {
        unsigned size;
        unsigned bot;
        unsigned top;
        char *buff;
        };
struct buff bf = {0,0,0,NULL};

initialisation:

bf.buff = malloc(SOME_SIZE);
        /* ... error checking omitted */
bp.size = SOME_SIZE;
bp.bot = bp.top =0;

reading:

unsigned todo;
int rc;

        /* (maybe) shift the buffer down to make place */
todo =  bf.top - bf.bot;
if (todo) {
        memmove (bf.buff, bf.buff + bf.bot, todo);
        bf.top = todo; bf.bot = 0;
        }

todo = bf.size - bf.top;

if (!todo) { /* maybe throttle? ... */ return; }
rc = read (fd, bf.buff+bp.top, todo);
        /* ... error checking omitted */
if (rc == -1) switch (errno) {...}
else if (rc == 0) {...}
else    {
        total_read += rc;
        bp.top +=  rc;
        }


writing:

unsigned todo; 
int rc;

todo =  bf.top - bf.bot;
if (!todo) { /* maybe juggle fd_set ... */ return; }
rc = write (fd, bf.buff+bp.bot, todo);
        /* ... error checking omitted */
if (rc == -1) switch (errno) {...}
else if (rc ==0) { ...}
else    {
        bp.bot += rc;
        total_written += rc;
        if (bp.bot == bp.top) bp.bot = bp.top =0;
        }
/* ... this is the place to juggle the fd_set for writing */
```