# ttyACM0 only reads 64 bytes

Tags: linux, termios

I'm bit of a newbie but I have an legacy app that reads 64 bytes of AES encrypted data from a device using ttyACM0.  I now need to read 128 bytes.  Sounded simple; increase the sizes of buffers etc. But no matter what I try, I still can only read 64 bytes.  After that it just hangs.  I verified the communications in Windows with a terminal and cdc-acm driver.  Device does not use flow control. I cant upload code because its proprietary but below are some snippets:

The Intialization:
        CACS_RefID::Initialise()
    {
        int iRet = 1;
        struct termios dev_settings;

```
    if(( m_fdRefdev = open("/dev/ttyACM0", O_RDWR))<0)
    {
        g_dbg->debug("CACS_RefID::Failed to open device\n");
        return 0;
    }


    g_dbg->debug("CACS_RefID::Initialse completed\n");
    // Configure the port
    tcgetattr(m_fdRefdev, &dev_settings);
    cfmakeraw(&dev_settings);

    //*tcflush 
    //tcflush(m_fdRefdev, TCIOFLUSH);   
     tcsetattr(m_fdRefdev, TCSANOW, &dev_settings);
    return iRet;
}
```

The implementation:

```
    int CACS_RefID::Readport_Refid(int ilen, char* buf)
{
    int ierr=0, iret = 0, ictr=0;
    fd_set  fdrefid;      
        struct timeval porttime_refrd;

    FD_ZERO(&fdrefid);
    FD_SET(m_fdRefdev,&fdrefid); 

    porttime_refrd.tv_sec = 1;
    porttime_refrd.tv_usec = 0; //10 Seconds wait time for read port

    do
    {
        iret = select(m_fdRefdev + 1, &fdrefid, NULL, NULL, &porttime_refrd);
        switch(iret)
        {
            case READ_TIMEOUT:
                g_dbg->debug("Refid portread: Select timeout:readlen=%d \n",ilen);
                ierr = -1;
                break;

            case READ_ERROR:
                g_dbg->debug("Refid portread: Select error:readlen=%d \n",ilen);
                ierr = -1; 
                break;

            default:
                iret = read(m_fdRefdev, buf, ilen); 
                g_dbg->debug("Refid portread: Read len(%d):%d\n",ilen,iret);
                break;
        }
    }while((ierr == 0) && (iret<ilen) );          

    //Flush terminal content at Input and Output after every read completion
//  tcflush(m_fdRefdev, TCIOFLUSH); 

    return ierr;
```

}

If I initialize every time that I before running the implementation, I get 128 bytes but the data is corrupt after 64 bytes.  Even before working on it, I get a lot of READ_ERRORs.  Looks like the original author expected the device to block with select() but it doesn't.
Is there some type of limitation on ttyACM0 buffer size in the system? Does baud rate matter with the ttyACM driver?  Does read() stop reading after all bytes are read (thinking the first 64 are available, then empty, then more data)?

Pouring thru man pages but I'm stymied.  ANY help would be greatly appreciated.

Heres my latest:

```
   int CACS_RefID::Get_GasTest_Result(int ilen)
{
    int ierr=0, iret = 0, ictr=0, iread=0;
    fd_set  fdrefid;      
        struct timeval porttime_refrd;

    porttime_refrd.tv_sec = 5;
    porttime_refrd.tv_usec = 0; //10 Seconds wait time for read port


    if (Get_GasTest_FirstPass == 0)
    {
        g_dbg->debug("GasTest_Result_firstPass\n");
        memset(strresult, 0, sizeof(strresult));        //SLY clear out result buffer
        iread=0;
        Get_GasTest_FirstPass = 1;
    }

    do
    {
        iread = strlen(strresult);

        FD_ZERO(&fdrefid);
        FD_SET(m_fdRefdev,&fdrefid); 

        iret = select(m_fdRefdev + 1, &fdrefid, NULL, NULL, &porttime_refrd);
        switch(iret)
        {
            case READ_TIMEOUT:      //0
                g_dbg->debug("Get_GasTest_Result: Select timeout\n");
                ierr = -1;
                break;

            case READ_ERROR:        //-1
                g_dbg->debug("Get_GasTest_Result: Select error=%d %s \n", errno,strerror(errno)) ;
                ierr = -1; 
                break;

        }
        iret = read(m_fdRefdev, (&strresult[0] + iread), (ilen-iread)); 
        g_dbg->debug("Get_GasTest_Result: ilen=%d,iret=%d,iread=%d \n",ilen,iret,iread);

    }while((ierr == 0) && (iread<ilen) );


    return ierr;
```

Note: I am now reading data regardless of select errors and STILL only getting 64bytes.  I've contacted my device mfg.  Must be something odd going on.

Comment: Have you tried just reading 64 bytes twice in a row?

Comment: A couple of things. What are READ_TIMEOUT and READ_ERROR? I can only infer that READ_TIMEOUT is 0 and READ_ERROR is -1. If you get READ_ERROR, you should look at errno and figure out what the error is. 

And no, nothing limits ttyACM0 to 64 bytes.

Finally, what is Readport_Refid() called with? it is sent in a buffer and a size, how big is the buffer?

Comment: Thank you for the response amrith. 
Your assumption re: READ_ERROR and READ_TIMEOUT is correct.  I have tried back to back reads of 64 bytes.  Should have mentioned that routines posted are the legacy code before all my attempts. The caller has sufficient space in the buffer.  Regards Steve

Comment: Why not try a single read and send down a buffer of 256 bytes?

Comment: You need to set the FD_SET before every call to select() (select changes it); so on every iteration of the loop. Also: a -1 return from select()could stem from an interrupted system call : check errno and act appropiately.

Comment: two ways to set buffer, i assume you use full-speed (because full speed EP size is 64 byte), 1 is buffer = 64byte, other is buffer = n*64bytes and n>1. Also you need rewrite you program of send data part, split the data into 64byte for each package

Comment: How, could you elaborate a bit, EP size.  If my buffer is Len 128 does that meet both criteria? What do I need to do to split into 2 packets: just back to back read (refdev,buff,64)?  Maybe incorporating wildplasser's comment from above.

Comment: `iread = strlen(strresult);`  You are assuming that the device never recieves a NUL character. You should instead do some real bookkeeping on how many characters you recieved, and howmany still to go. Also: your ierr variable is not initialised. A compiler could detect this, so you won't need proofreaders.

Comment: BTW: since there is no guarantee that you will recieve the 128 bytes in one read() call, you need to buffer the partial data and save it between calls. (And: **don't** assume it to be NUL-terminated) For an example of buffering, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9315575/905902

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible problem with your code; this may not be the one that is causing you to only get 64 bytes but it could explain what you are seeing. Assume that you invoke the function Readport_Refid() with a buffer of 128 bytes. In other words, your invocation was something like:

```
char buffer[128];

Readport_Refid(128, buffer);
```

Assume for whatever reason that the first call to select() gets you a return value of 1 (since one bit is set). Your code is only setting one bit so you go off and you read()

```
iret = read(m_fdRefdev, buf, ilen); 
g_dbg->debug("Refid portread: Read len(%d):%d\n",ilen,iret);
break;
```

iret returns 64 (which means 64 bytes are read) and your program prints a nice message and since ierr is still 0 and iret (64) is less than ilen (128) you go round again and call select().

Assume that you get more data and select() returns 1 again. Then you will go read again on the same buffer with the same ilen and overwrite the first 64 bytes that were read.

At the very least, you should do the following. I have only shown below the changed lines. First add an iread variable and make sure you use it to preserve data that you've already read. Then use iread to determine whether you've read enough or not.

```
int CACS_RefID::Readport_Refid(int ilen, char* buf)
{
    int ierr=0, iret = 0, ictr=0, iread = 0;

    [...]
            default:
                iret = read(m_fdRefdev, buf + iread, ilen - iread); 
                if (iret > 0)
                    iread += iret;

                g_dbg->debug("Refid portread: Read len(%d):%d\n",ilen,iret);
                break;
        }
    }while((ierr == 0) && (iread<ilen) );          

    [...]
```

**** EDITED 2013-08-19 ****

I want to reiterate a comment made by [@wildplasser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/905902/wildplasser)

You should really also be setting FD_SET on each trip around the loop. Great catch.

With respect to your new code, does it work or do you still have a problem?

**** EDITED again 2013-08-19 ****

Getting EINTR is nothing to be worried about. You should just plan on resetting FD_SET and trying again.

Comment: Thanks I really need to post latest code when I get to work.  I moved strresult into a class variable and append received data to preserve.  I tried doing a single char read.

Comment: Here is my latest code.  It is called by caller until 128 bytes is received.  I added errno and get A LOT of interupted system call - almost everytime this code gets run.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I know why but the fix was to call the initialization code at the beginning of the implementation even though it is called previously.  If I call it again, I can read in 128 bytes.  If I don't, I can only read up to 64 bytes.