# Strange looping with socket communication

Tags: c, sockets, fork

I am pretty new to socket programming, and I'm having trouble debugging the following code:

Client:

```
#define SIZE sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    printf("Starting setup\n");
    int sockfd;
    int adder;
    int sum;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(7013);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &server.sin_addr.s_addr);

    printf("Setup complete\n");

    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("Socket call failed.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    else{
        printf("socket: %i", sockfd);
    }

    //connect the socket
    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &server, SIZE) == -1) {
        perror("Connect call failed");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    //Send and receive
    while (!feof(stdin)) {
        printf("Input an integer \n");
        adder = atoi(fgets(intChar, 11, stdin));
        if ((send(sockfd, &adder, 11, 0)) == -1) {
            perror("Send error");
        }
        if (recv(sockfd, &sum, 1, 0) > 0) {
            printf("%d", sum);
        }
        else {
            printf("Server has died \n");
            close(sockfd);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Server:

```
int sum = 0;
int numconnections = 0;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int sockfd;
    int newsockfd;
    int adder = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(7013);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    printf("Starting up. \n");
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    //Free port
    int on = 1;
    setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &on, sizeof(on));
    if (sockfd == -1) {
        perror("Socket call failed. \n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    //bind address
    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &server, sizeof(server)) == -1) {
        perror("Bind call failed. \n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    //listen
    if (listen(sockfd, 5) == -1) {
        perror("Listen call failed. \n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    while (numconnections < 2) {
        //accept a connection
        printf("ready to accept connections\n");
        if ((newsockfd = accept(sockfd, NULL, NULL)) == -1) {
            perror("Accept call failed. \n");
            continue;
        }
        printf("New connection detected");
        numconnections++;
        //spawn child to deal with it
        if (fork() == 0) {
            while (recv(newsockfd, &adder, 1, 0) > 0) {
                printf("Sum is %d \n", sum);
                printf("Adder is %d \n", adder);
                sum += adder;
                printf("Sending sum %d \n", sum);
                send(newsockfd, &sum, 1, 0);
            }
            close(newsockfd);
            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        }
    }
    close(newsockfd);
        close(sockfd);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Regardless of whether I run the programs on the same machine or separate, when the server receives a socket it proceeds to add numbers about 10 times in succession, almost as if the socket is looping.

Here is some sample output after I submit a 3 from the client:

```
Starting up. 
ready to accept connections
New connection detectedready to accept connections
New connection detectedSum is 0 
Adder is 3 
Sending sum 3 
Sum is 3 
Adder is 0 
Sending sum 3 
Sum is 3 
Adder is 0 
Sending sum 3 
Sum is 3 
Adder is 0 
Sending sum 3 
Sum is 3 
Adder is 77 
Sending sum 80 
Sum is 80 
Adder is 11 
Sending sum 91 
Sum is 91 
Adder is 64 
Sending sum 155 
Sum is 155 
Adder is 0 
Sending sum 155 
Sum is 155 
Adder is 3 
Sending sum 158 
Sum is 158 
Adder is 0 
Sending sum 158 
Sum is 158 
Adder is 0 
Sending sum 158
```

On the client side, I get back the 3 initially, but then I get some nonsense number like 4197123.

I have a strong feeling that I am missing something obvious. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `while (recv(newsockfd, &adder, 1, 0) > 0) {` use the return value from recv() is is the nimner of bytes actually recieved. The third argument is also wrong.

Comment: Oh I see, the third argument is for the buffer size, so I should use sizeof(int).

Comment: At least. Or buffer between calls, which is necessary, since TCP has no message boundaries: the stream can be broken up at any point.

Comment: I changed the while loop to an if statement, and the server end is good now, only printing once. However, the client still recieves back the initial sum and then a nonsense value.

Comment: You changed the third argument for send(), too ?

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot about that. Also, the nonsense value is the value of the socket, I forgot I was printing that.

Comment: Ok perfect. If you want to summarize that material in an answer I would be happy to accept it. Otherwise, I will just do it myself and accept my own answer I guess :P.

Comment: `if ((send(sockfd, &adder, 11, 0)) == -1) {` is also very wrong (client) you are sending an int, not the string.

Comment: Yes, I fixed that one too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while (recv(newsockfd, &adder, 1, 0) > 0) { ...
```

use the return value from recv() It is the number of bytes actually recieved. The third argument is also wrong. It should at least sizeof(int). Or you could buffer the partial receptions between calls, which is necessary, since TCP has no message boundaries: the stream can be broken up at any point. (see my sketch for buffering [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9315575/905902))

You should also change the third argument for send(); `send()` is similar.

```
adder = atoi(fgets(intChar, 11, stdin));
if ((send(sockfd, &adder, 11, 0)) == -1) { ...
```

(client) is also very wrong  you are sending an int, not the string.

Finally: don't use `feof()`, at least not in this way. feof() will return non-zero **after** the fgets() has failed, the NULL argument will probably allready havecrash atoi().

Comment: I removed the client loop, it was unnecessary anyway.